# Habilitar Iframe em aplicação asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis

possuo uma aplicação asp.net e preciso colocá-la dentro de um Iframe.

Acontece que ele dá erro no console do Chrome:

```
Refused to display 'domain' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

No mozilla ele nao dá erro, e também não mostra nada.

o WebConfig já está assim:

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Não sei o que fazer.

Answer (score 0):

No seu `Global.asax.cs`, defina o seguinte:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
}
```

Aplicações ASP.NET MVC não estão configuradas por padrão para aparecerem em `iframes`.

Comment: Posso fazer isso no IIS de alguma forma? Estou evitando republicar a aplicação

Comment: Em teoria tem, mas não funciona direito. Esta é a melhor alternativa.